# Pushing files and folders to a specific folder on ftp

Tags: shell-script, ftp

I'm building a website, which I'm pushing online using Filezilla. But this is monotonous and I'm sure could be done with a script. So far I figured out this much:

I connect with the ftp server using `ftp mydomain.com` I give my credentials and all is great. But this is how my project files look like:

```
asset-manifest.json - file
assets - folder
favicon.ico - file
index.html - file
manifest.json - file
og-image.png - file
service-worker.js - file
static - folder
```

So there are folders. From what I saw I cannot push folders using the `ftp` command. I saw there is something like [ncftp](https://www.ncftp.com/download/), but the syntax is a little weird. I don't see how I could traverse to the right folder. This is the path when I run `pwd` in the destination folder on the `ftp` folder:

```
257 "/websites/uczIchApp" is your current location
```

So how I'd do it locally is more or less this:

```
yarn build
mv * -r /websites/myDestFolder
```

How can I replicate it with `ftp`? I'm open to using other commands instead of `ftp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is how I ended up doing it:

```
yarn build
ncftpput -R -v -u "User" -p "Password" domain /path/to/ build/*
```

I used this answer:

https://superuser.com/a/841862